# Sending user uploaded images to backend using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python

I am trying to send images to my backend to be stored in a database using a byte format. The images are uploaded by a user and I am not sure what format they will be in.

What is the best way to convert the image to a format that can be send via network request to a python server and stored in a database.

currently I just have this function:

```
  function onLogoChange(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      let img = event.target.files[0];
      setFormData({
        name: "logo",
        value: URL.createObjectURL(img),
      });
    }
  }
```

This seems to send something. However I haven't been able to retrieve these images and I think the reason is because they are not formatted correctly going into the db.

Comment: Are you using any python framework for the backend? If you really want to save the images in the db then you can convert them to bytes and save them in a varbinary column. However, it's advisable to use a file storage system like cloudinary and only store the link to the image in the database

Comment: @narravabrion I have been bouncing between both methods (using an s3 bucket and using a DB). I haven't had success with either and I think the reason is my front end is not configuring the data properly to be sent via network request.

Comment: Depending on the framework you are using for your backend then how you get the sent files in the backend is different. For example DRF picks up the images automatically without extra configs. While using flask I had to pick the json data separately from the file data

Comment: @narravabrion Got it. When trying to upload to a DB I am using psycopg2. and when trying to upload to an s3 bucket I am using boto3.

Comment: You can upload to s3 then await a response then save the returned URL to the postgres. Sorry I've only implemented this with cloudinary  and they provide detailed docs

Comment: I havent been able to send the right data to my server to actually upload the image to s3 :/